# How to fix/optimize document detection with a lot of noise

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, edge-detection, canny-operator

I build a python script to detect and extract documents/citizen cards from a image, it was working as i wanted until i tried a spanish citizen card (DNI 3.0).

When i perform canny edge algorythm on this card, it has a lot of noise/lines/things that merge into the edges of the card and thats what **i think** its causing the issue.

**Canny edge applied:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
def attemptPerspectiveTransform(openCVImage, debug_mode):

image = openCVImage
ratio = image.shape[0] / 300.0
orig = image.copy()
image = imutils.resize(image, height = 300)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 0, 200)

if (debug_mode == True):
    cv2.imshow("gray", gray)
    cv2.imshow("edged", edged)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]

screenCnt = None

for c in cnts:

    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)

    print('APPROX')
    print(len(approx))

    # if our approximated contour has four points, should be the document we are looking for
    if len(approx) == 4:
        screenCnt = approx

        break

# now that we have our screen contour, we need to determine
# the top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left
# points so that we can later warp the image -- we'll start
# by reshaping our contour to be our finals and initializing
# our output rectangle in top-left, top-right, bottom-right,
# and bottom-left order

pts = screenCnt.reshape(4, 2)
rect = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype = "float32")

# the top-left point has the smallest sum whereas the
# bottom-right has the largest sum
s = pts.sum(axis = 1)
rect[0] = pts[np.argmin(s)]
rect[2] = pts[np.argmax(s)]

# compute the difference between the points -- the top-right
# will have the minumum difference and the bottom-left will
# have the maximum difference
diff = np.diff(pts, axis = 1)
rect[1] = pts[np.argmin(diff)] 
rect[3] = pts[np.argmax(diff)]

# multiply the rectangle by the original ratio
rect *= ratio

# now that we have our rectangle of points, let's compute
# the width of our new image
(tl, tr, br, bl) = rect

widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))

# ...and now for the height of our new image
heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))

# take the maximum of the width and height values to reach
# our final dimensions
maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))
maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB))

# construct our destination points which will be used to
# map the screen to a top-down, "birds eye" view
dst = np.array([
    [0, 0],
    [maxWidth - 1, 0],
    [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
    [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype = "float32")

# calculate the perspective transform matrix and warp
# the perspective to grab the screen
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
warp = cv2.warpPerspective(orig, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))

# convert the warped image to grayscale and then adjust
# the intensity of the pixels to have minimum and maximum
# values of 0 and 255, respectively
warp = cv2.cvtColor(warp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
warp = exposure.rescale_intensity(warp, out_range = (0, 255))

height, width = warp.shape

if (height > width):
    warp = rotate_image(warp, 90)

if (debug_mode == True):
    # show images
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
    cv2.imshow("edge", edged)
    cv2.imshow("warp", imutils.resize(warp, height = 300))
    cv2.imshow("warp pure", imutils.resize(warp, height = 300))
    cv2.imwrite('cropped_final.jpg', warp)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

return warp
```

**Results in error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 60, in <module>
    cv_front_cropped_path = image_preprocessing.processImage(front_img, debug_mode)
  File "/Users/duarteandrade/Desktop/OCR-DEMO/PythonOCR/pyocr/image_preprocessing.py", line 179, in processImage
    image = perspective_transform.attemptPerspectiveTransform(image, debug_mode)
  File "/Users/duarteandrade/Desktop/OCR-DEMO/PythonOCR/pyocr/perspective_transform.py", line 84, in attemptPerspectiveTransform
    pts = screenCnt.reshape(4, 2)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

It works good with the portuguese citizen card with worse images, i guess because it doesnt have those lines at the top of the card and all the noise that can be seen in the spanish card.

**How can i fix this ?**

**Original image : **

[image]

Comment: Have you tried noise reducing algorithm? Not sure what kind of noise is problematic here, if it's the added pictures on the card it won't do much.

Comment: Yes, i tried, seems to not have any effect

Comment: What are the results like when you don't resize the image?

Comment: Could you add your original input image and an expected output image?

Comment: Sorry for the delay @nathancy, i added the image, the expected output is the cropped document wich means no errors as its happening now.

Comment: Do I understand right that your end goal is to find the citizenship card in the arbitrary image and extract it?

Comment: Exactly @Dmytro

Comment: How do background lines prevent from detecting? I mean what information from the residence card makes it detectable? Nevertheless, what you can try is to get rid of the background lines by color: filter out all the pixels where RGB values differ from each other more than certain threshold. Alternatively you can also try to do erode/dilate with a small kernel to get rid of thin lines.